# Why does malloc throw a "corrupted top size" error when memory is allocated for a struct?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I have a struct that I am using, and I have written a method to create and initialize it.  The method throws a corrupted top size error when I malloc memory for the struct.  Here is the code for the struct:

```
typedef struct Job {
  int id;
  int cpuBurst;
  int ioBurst;
  int repetitions;
  int priority;
  int startTime;
  int endTime;
  int waitTime;
}Job;
```

and the method:

```
Job * createJob(int id, int cpuBurst, int ioBurst, int repetitions, int priority) {
  Job *job = (Job *) malloc(sizeof(Job));
  job->id = id;
  job->cpuBurst = cpuBurst;
  job->ioBurst = ioBurst;
  job->repetitions = repetitions;
  job->priority = priority;
  job->startTime = -1;
  job->endTime = -1;
  job->waitTime = 0;
  
  return job;
}
```

`Job *job = (Job *) malloc(sizeof(Job));` throws the error.

I have looked around for similar questions, but all the ones I could find had to do with buffer overflow, and I don't think that's my problem as I'm not using a buffer.

Comment: The corruption had already happened prior to this call.

Comment: I can't duplicate the error/issue.  Code Seems to work fine.  I'm thinking it's like @user207421 said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error (corrupted top size) is the sort of error you get if something has *already* corrupted the heap before your `malloc` call. It's usually the `malloc` code checking its internal data structures for sanity before potentially causing *more* damage.

You probably need to look at *other* code to find out why since, aside from one issue (see below), your code is safe.

---

As an aside, you shouldn't explicitly cast the return value of `malloc` in C, it's not necessary and it can hide certain subtle bugs.

And you should *definitely* compare the return value against `NULL` before attempting to use it. Failing to do so will likely also crash your code.

Comment: You were right.  The issue was elsewhere.  Thanks for the tips about using malloc.  :)